# App Crashes due to Orientation

Tags: android, orientation

This is my code for `onCreate()`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(new GameView(this));
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}
```

For some reason, some of the phones I've tested this app on cause the app to crash when it is opened in portrait mode. The app is supposed to and is set to be played in landscape mode. If, however, you open the app while holding the phone landscape style, it does open and will not crash.

I need the app not to crash when opened in portrait mode, and then it needs to go to landscape mode.

Thanks.

Comment: put `setContentView(new GameView(this));` before `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

Comment: Where's the log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give screen orientation in manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".LoginPage"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your manifest file in your activity.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```